# TFS 2015 Build Stuck at "The build has been queued and is waiting to start."

Tags: svn, tfs, build, continuous-integration, tfs-2015

We have TFS 2015 Update 1 On-Premises. Just starting out using the Build stuff.

I've setup a build agent and have a test build definition with no steps in it. When I set the repository type to Team Foundation Version Control the build runs fine. But when I switch the repository type to SVN (what I really want to use), the build is stuck at "The build has been queued and is waiting to start".

This is the exact same build definition. It goes back and forth between working and not working as I switch the repo type. I've setup the agent to just run in the command line window so I can see what it's doing. When the build is set to TFVC you can see the agent pick it up and do stuff. When the build is set to SVN the agent does nothing at all. Almost like TFS is not sending it to the agent because I'm using SVN. Why?

Looks to be a similar issue but no solution: [TFS 2015 Update 1 RC 2 Subversion support in build hangs indefinitely](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ba9d2a3-85bf-4539-b956-382d26e3024b/tfs-2015-update-1-rc-2-subversion-support-in-build-hangs-indefinitely?forum=tfsbuild)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a test build definition with build steps and make sure have followed this [tutorial](https://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/integrations/subversion).

Building with svn repository and TFVC both works well on TFS 2015 update3 and TFS15.

Although this is not a real solution, however update your TFS version will fix the issue.

Comment: I believe that was the tutorial I had originally followed. Just upgraded to TFS 2015 Update 3 and now the agent picks up the build. But the build fails with an error that may be a clue as to why it wasn't picked up before. Maybe. The error is "The Subversion source code provider requires the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Runtime to be installed on this Build Agent machine." So I will install that. But for this exact question, solved!